# Manually Insert Data into Firebase database and show them in my android app as ListView

Tags: listview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create an Alumni database for my android app with Firebase Realtime Database. I want to insert the data from the Firebase console manually. Now my first question is how to do that (An example structure of the database would be helpful). My database has 3 fields (Name, Designation and Workplace).

Secondly, after adding the data, how can I show them in my app as a ListView. I also want to add a filter option for my database. I already created the model class and the list layout.

**Alumni class:**

```
public class Alumni {

    String name = null;
    String designation = null;
    String workplace = null;

    public Alumni(String name, String designation, String workplace) {
        this.name = name;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.workplace = workplace;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public String getWorkplace() {
        return workplace;
    }

    public void setWorkplace(String workplace) {
        this.workplace = workplace;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + designation + " " + workplace;
    }
}
```

**list_row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_work"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon_work"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_workplace"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/designation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon_work"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/icon_work"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text="@string/bar"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/designation"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/designation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/workplace"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

A link of article regarding this type of example will be helpful